# create multiple x y charts, one for each column with the same x axis using excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working on the problem of automating the plotting of line diagrams. But I did not yet manage to solve it yet.

I would need multiple charts one for each column (from E to R) using the same column (B) for the X axis. The ultimate aim is to be able to clean out the extreme or outlying values.

I would need multiple charts one for each column (from E to R) using the same column (B) for the X axis.

Could anyone please help me with this problem, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

After recording a macro on one of the worksheets and editing the code I got the following:

I edited it so only the name of the worksheet has to be changed  because all the 30 worksheets I have to run this on have the same structure. Now you should have to change the reference to the name of the worksheet, but the best would be if it could run automatically for all the sheets in the actual file.

Unfortunately it stops after the first graph giving me a runtime error.

```
Sub plot()
'
' plot Makró
'
' have to change 'st1' to the name of the actual worksheet

    Range("B:B,E:E").Select
    Range("E1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'st2'!$B:$B,'st2'!$E:$E")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 1").IncrementLeft 599.25
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 1").IncrementTop -70.5

    Range("B:B,F:F").Select
    Range("F1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'st2'!$B:$B,'st2'!$F:$F")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 2").IncrementLeft 601.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 2").IncrementTop 152.25

      Range("B:B,G:G").Select
    Range("G1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'st2'!$B:$B,'st2'!$G:$G")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 3").IncrementLeft 601.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 3").IncrementTop 372.25

    Range("B:B,H:H").Select
    Range("H1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'st2'!$B:$B,'st2'!$H:$H")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 4").IncrementLeft 601.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 4").IncrementTop 592.25

    Range("B:B,I:I").Select
    Range("I1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'st2'!$B:$B,'st2'!$I:$I")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 5").IncrementLeft 601.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 5").IncrementTop 812.25

    Range("B:B,J:J").Select
    Range("J1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'st2'!$B:$B,'st2'!$J:$J")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 6").IncrementLeft 601.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 6").IncrementTop 1032.25

    Range("B:B,K:K").Select
    Range("K1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'st2'!$B:$B,'st2'!$K:$K")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 7").IncrementLeft 601.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 7").IncrementTop 1252.25

    Range("B:B,L:L").Select
    Range("L1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'st2'!$B:$B,'st2'!$L:$L")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 8").IncrementLeft 601.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 8").IncrementTop 1472.25

    Range("B:B,M:M").Select
    Range("M1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'st2'!$B:$B,'st2'!$M:$M")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 9").IncrementLeft 601.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 9").IncrementTop 1692.25

    Range("B:B,N:N").Select
    Range("N1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'st2'!$B:$B,'st2'!$N:$N")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 9").IncrementLeft 601.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 9").IncrementTop 1912.25

    Range("B:B,O:O").Select
    Range("O1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'st2'!$B:$B,'st2'!O:$O")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 10").IncrementLeft 601.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 10").IncrementTop 2132.25

      Range("B:B,P:P").Select
    Range("P1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'st2'!$B:$B,'st2'!P:$P")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 11").IncrementLeft 601.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 11").IncrementTop 2351.25

        Range("B:B,Q:Q").Select
    Range("Q1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'st2'!$B:$B,'st2'!Q:$Q")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 12").IncrementLeft 601.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 12").IncrementTop 2572.25

        Range("B:B,R:R").Select
    Range("R1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'st2'!$B:$B,'st2'!R:$R")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 13").IncrementLeft 601.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 13").IncrementTop 2792.25

End Sub
```

Comment: Try recording a macro while creating a couple of charts, then try editing the resulting code.  Post back with code if you run into problems

Comment: I recorded a pilot version ,but I still encountered major issues. I tried to explain them in the edited original question.

Thank you for your help again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to restructure and rethink the whole script and place it in a loop. Now it works perfectly.

```
Sub plot()
Dim c As Range
Dim D As Range
Dim xaxis As Range
Dim WKS As Worksheet
Dim Prior As Worksheet
Dim chrt As Chart
Dim I As Integer 'counter for chart placement
I = 1

Set D = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Set Prior = ActiveSheet

Set WKS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(, Prior)
WKS.Name = Prior.Name & " Charts"
Prior.Activate


For Each c In D.Rows(1).Cells

Select Case c.Value

Case "Stat", "year", "month"
'do nothing
Case "date_1900"
'set xaxis
Set xaxis = c.Resize(D.Rows.Count, 1)

'first cells of the columns
Case "Temp", "pH", "Cond.", "O2", "Na", "Cl", "HCO3", "CO3", "TP",    "NH4-N", "NO3-N", "Chla", "Secchi", "FC/EC_converted to fitered"
'add a new sheet


Set chrt = WKS.Shapes.AddChart.Chart


With chrt

.ChartType = xlLineMarkers

.SetSourceData Source:=Union(xaxis, c.Resize(D.Rows.Count, 1))

    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = c.Value
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Date"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = c.Value

    .Parent.Top = Range("A1").Offset((I - 5) * 15, 0).Top
     .Parent.Left = Range("A1").Offset((I - 5) * 15, 0).Left


End With

End Select
Set chrt = Nothing

I = I + 1
Next c

Set D = Nothing
Set WKS = Nothing
Set Prior = Nothing
Set xaxis = Nothing

End Sub
```